# find four of a kind in a poker hand

Tags: mysql

Here are my tables

```
pokerHands
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+
| playerId | gameId | R1 | R2  | R3 | R4 | R5 |
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+
|    12789 | 17MET  | QH | QS  | 3D | 3C | 3H |
|    12789 | 82SAT  | 7C | 4S  | 4D | 4C | 3H |
|    56347 | 03DEC  | 3S | 6S  | 3H | 3C | 3D |
|    56347 | 23WSA  | KH | 10H | 7H | 3H | AH |
|    84643 | 78GUV  | 9H | 7C  | 5H | 5C | 2S |
|    90734 | 65YOB  | QH | JH  | 8C | 8S | 8D |
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+

select * from pokerCards limit 5;
+----------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+
| cardName | face | type | suit | faceValue | gameValue |
+----------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+
| 10C      | no   | 10   | C    |        10 |        10 |
| 10D      | no   | 10   | D    |        10 |        10 |
| 10H      | no   | 10   | H    |        10 |        10 |
| 10S      | no   | 10   | S    |        10 |        10 |
| 2C       | no   | 2    | C    |         2 |         2 |
+----------+------+------+------+-----------+-----------+
```

playerId and gameId are composite PRIMARY KEYS in the first table pokerHands, while cardName is the PRIMARY KEY of the second table.

I'm trying to find out how to select a four of a kind from the first table which would return this from the current pokerHands table

```
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+
| playerId | gameId | R1 | R2  | R3 | R4 | R5 |
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+
|    56347 | 03DEC  | 3S | 6S  | 3H | 3C | 3D |
+----------+--------+----+-----+----+----+----+
```

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider revising your schema.

Comment: Anything you have tried yourself?

Comment: Tip: Don't represent 10s as `10C` and such, keep it as *always* two letter codes: `TC` where `T` means "ten". Another thing that helps is sorting the hand and putting it into a single string field so that patterns are obvious. `T?T?T?T?` is going to be four tens and you can easily match this with a regular expression.

Comment: @ Strawberry - unfortunately the schema is out of my control, it's what I have to work with.

Comment: Well I would start with a bunch of unions, so as to create a pseudo normalised environment. Oh, and I'd use 0 instead of T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select playerId, gameId, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5 from pokerHands as ph
join pokerCards as pc1 on pc1.cardName=ph.R1
join pokerCards as pc2 on pc2.cardName=ph.R2
join pokerCards as pc3 on pc3.cardName=ph.R3
join pokerCards as pc4 on pc4.cardName=ph.R4
join pokerCards as pc5 on pc5.cardName=ph.R5
where ( (pc1.type=pc2.type) and (pc1.type=pc3.type) and (pc1.type=pc4.type) )
or ( (pc1.type=pc2.type) and (pc1.type=pc3.type) and (pc1.type=pc5.type) )
or ( (pc1.type=pc2.type) and (pc1.type=pc4.type) and (pc1.type=pc5.type) )
or ( (pc1.type=pc3.type) and (pc1.type=pc4.type) and (pc1.type=pc5.type) )
or ( (pc2.type=pc3.type) and (pc2.type=pc4.type) and (pc2.type=pc5.type) )
```

Comment: That worked a treat!! return exactly one row as expected.  Thanks for your help !

Comment: is it possible to do this using a count function e.g.

having count(suit) = 4

Answer (score 0):

Your life would be easier if you had your cards inserted into R1-R5 in rank order. Then you could check two cases (where the cards are bunched LEFT or RIGHT)

```
rank(r1)==rank(r2) and rank(r1)==rank(r3) and rank(r1)==rank(r4)
OR
rank(r2)==rank(r3) and rank(r2)==rank(r4) and rank(r2)==rank(r5)
```

Comment: Yep, I fully agree with you, but that may not always be the case.  Given me something to think about though.. Thanks for you reply